# Working out a sum total cost where purchases and prices are in separate tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables in my Reward System's database:

`purchases` => `Purchase_ID`, `Datetime`, `Reward_ID`, `Quantity`, `Student_ID`, `Student_Name`, `Date_DealtWith`, `Date_Collected`

`rewards` => `Reward_ID`, `Title`, `Description`, `Image_URL`, `Date_Inactive`, `Stock_Count`, `Cost_to_User`, `Cost_to_System`

What I'd like to do is **produce a sum total of purchased rewards**. So for example, if 10 rewards had been purchased at 5 points each, I would like to display the total of *50*. The cost to the student is the `Cost_to_User` field.

I was previously trying to use this code:

```
SELECT SUM(  `purchases`.`Quantity` ) *  `rewards`.`Cost_to_User` AS  `Total_Points_Spent` 
FROM  `purchases` 
INNER JOIN  `rewards` ON  `purchases`.`Reward_ID` =  `rewards`.`Reward_ID`"
```

But it seems to be presuming that each reward is worth 100 points - coincidentally the first reward in the `rewards` table has a `Cost_to_User` of 100 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the second bracket to be after the Cost_to_user:

```
select sum(purchases.Quantity * rewards.Cost_to_User) as Total_points_spent
```

You were finding a total quantity rather than calculating per row

Answer (score 1):

Are you grouping by `Cost_to_User`?

Otherwise, compute the sum of the products instead of the product of the sums.

```
SELECT SUM(  `purchases`.`Quantity` *  `rewards`.`Cost_to_User` ) AS  `Total_Points_Spent`
```

Comment: Thanks Joel - given the answer to KAJ just because his wording made a tiny little bit more sense to me.